# Polars add column with counted items from series of list[str]

Tags: rust, counting, rust-polars

After splitting a string in multiple 'words', I want to add a new column with the amount of counted items `.alias("count")`.

```
let df = df! [
        "keys" => ["a ab", "a ab abc", "b ba abc abcd", "b ba bbc abcd bbcd"],
        "groups" => ["A", "A", "B", "C"],
    ]?;
```

First I split the string:

```
let out = df.lazy().with_column(col("keys").str().split(" "));
```

And attempt the count:

```
let out_2 = out.with_columns([col("keys")
      .apply(|s| Ok(s.len()), GetOutput::from_type(DataType::Int32))
      .alias("count")]).collect().unwrap();
```

Which results in error message:

```
mismatched types
expected struct `polars::prelude::Series`, found `usize`
```

No idea how to proceed.

Comment: Which version of polars do you use? With `0.27.2` not even the snippet for splitting the strings compiles...

Comment: It's 0.25.1 actually. And you probably need feature "strings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.arr()`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/enum.Expr.html#method.arr) method to get a [`ListNameSpace`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.ListNameSpace.html), which provides [`lengths`](https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/struct.ListNameSpace.html#method.lengths).

```rust
let out_2 = out
        .with_columns([col("keys").arr().lengths().alias("count")])
        .collect()
        .unwrap();
```

```
┌─────────────────────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ keys                    ┆ groups ┆ count │
│ ---                     ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ list[str]               ┆ str    ┆ u32   │
╞═════════════════════════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ ["a", "ab"]             ┆ A      ┆ 2     │
│ ["a", "ab", "abc"]      ┆ A      ┆ 3     │
│ ["b", "ba", ... "abcd"] ┆ B      ┆ 4     │
│ ["b", "ba", ... "bbcd"] ┆ C      ┆ 5     │
└─────────────────────────┴────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why your solution stopped working in Polars 0.29 (and perhaps even before that version)?